# Convert an int to a string with 2 digits in C++

Tags: c++, formatting, converters

I have the following code in C++, which is supposed to take `led_pwm` hexadecimal variable, and convert it into a string `led_pwm_string`.

```
long int led_pwm=0x0a;

std::ostringstream ostr;
ostr << std::hex << led_pwm; //use the string stream just like cout,
                             //except the stream prints not to stdout 
                             //but to a string.

std::string led_pwm_string = ostr.str(); //the str() function of the stream
                                         //returns the string
```

The only issue I have with this code, is that for any value of `led_pwm` between `0x00` and `0x0a`, it converts into a single digit in `led_pwm_string`. This creates problems for me later on.

I would like, in every possible circumstance, that `led_pwm_string` contains always a 2 digit string. So if `led_pwm` is `0x01` (for example), then `led_pwm_string` will be `01`, and not just `1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
ostr << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << led_pwm;
```

You might need to `#include <iomanip>`.